# Add a pdf to a Reporting Services report after rendering report as pdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, pdf-generation, reportingservices-2005

We are using Reporting Services to generate a purchase order, which is rendered as pdf before displaying on the screen.  The report works well, as is, except that now we have to add a Terms & Conditions page to every PO.  I've tried placing it in the footer, setting it to display only on the last page--this didn't work. I've also tried adding it to the body, setting the "Page Break Before" property to "true".  This works, except that it looks like there is still space reserved for the header (i.e. the header's "show on last page" property is set to false).  I can't get the Terms & conditions to fill the page.

Does anyone know how I could attach or bind the pdf generated by reporting services with a pdf version of the Terms & Conditions sheet?

Note:  We are using ASP & VB.NET 2.0, Visual Studio 2005, & SQL Server 2005.

Comment: How big is the header area?  Why do you need the terms and conditions to fill the entire page, including the header area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question that may satisfy your requirements was posted and answered later today:

[Combine two (or more) PDF's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808670/combine-two-or-more-pdfs)

Check out the PDFSharp...that looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp (a port of the java version iText) is a good open source library that we are using to do just that.