# Add additional static page to end of an SSRS report with no header/footer

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a requirement for a user to have a either a static pdf or static image to be uploaded to the database. That needs to be appended to the end of an SSRS report. The report has a header and footer, which cannot be displayed on the last page and no body can be displayed either. The report must basically generate its report completely, then append a full page with just the static piece.

I have tried to expand the footer out to an additional full page height minus the margins, so 8.5 - .25(top margin) - .25(bottom margin). This produces really funky results. There is a first page with a header and a second page with the header/body/footer, but the pages are something like 14-15 inches tall instead of page breaking it actually reformats the page.

Is there a way to append an image(or PDF) that takes up a whole page to the end of an ssrs report without the header/footers?

Comment: Is your report just a 1 page report with header and footer? and you want to add another page without header and footer is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is the idea, but the header and footer height are static, so even if i make them invisible, the white space that take up looks worse that leaving them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

- create a new report
- add a Rectangle region, size it to the whole page
- set the Page Break > BreakLocation property of the rectangle to "End"
- add a Subreport inside the Rectangle and set it to your original report

The new report should then generate the original report plus an extra page.

Answer (score -1):

As the additional page is static you could simply create a new PDF and merge it at the end of the report when exporting to PDF.

Both [`PDFSharp`](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1) and [`iTextSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/) are possible libraries you could use to merge PDF files, there are plenty of tutorials and demos you could consult. Even here on StackOverflow for example: [Combine two (or more) PDF's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808670/combine-two-or-more-pdfs)

Comment: Workaround - because your answer suggests use of additional software to overcome the solution. I would have expected an answer which has a solution within SSRS. Thanks!